# Eliminar margin al hacer hover

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema con el menú:

> Al pasar el puntero por las opciones que tienen submenús, éstos se mueven o se alteran.

Ya le intenté alinear los textos con **`text-align`**, pero nada.

Este es el código sobre el que estoy trabajando:

```css
.navlistmain {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    right: 5px;
}

.navlistmain ul {
 display: flex;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 }

.navlistmain a {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #191C26;
 }

.navlistmain a:hover {
 color: #bcbcbc;
 }

#navlistmain ul li {
        float: left;
    }

.navlistmain ul li ul {
 display: none;
 }

.navlistmain ul li a:hover + ul, .navlistmain ul li ul:hover {
 display: block;
 }

.listmain {
    font-family: 'Conv_TradeGothicLTStd-BdCn20';
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #303030;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    list-style: none;
}

.listmain a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.listmain:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.listmain:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navlistmain">
            <ul>
                <li class="listmain"><a href="Repertorio/Novelas.php">Novelas</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="listmain"><a href="Repertorio/Novelas/La Pasión de Ania.php">La Pasión de Ania</a></li>
                        <li class="listmain"><a href="Repertorio/Novelas/Noesunanovelarosa.php">No es una novela rosa</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="listmain"><a href="Repertorio/Series.php">Serie de Historias</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="listmain"><a href="Repertorio/HistoriasCortas/index.php">Historias Cortas</a></li>
                        <li class="listmain"><a href="Repertorio/Patricio yPatricia/index.php">Patricio y Patricia</a></li>
                        <li class="listmain"><a href="Repertorio/index.php">Más historias</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="listmain"><a href="About/Autor.php">Sobre el Autor</a></li>
                <li class="listmain"><a href="About/Company.php">Sobre HC</a></li>
                <li class="listmain"><a href="Newsfeed/Noticias.php">Noticias</a></li>
                <li class="listmain"><a href="Contacto/index.php">Contacto</a></li>
                <li class="listmain"><a href="#">El Blog de LRyA</a></li>
            </ul></nav>
```

> Estoy trabajando el menú sobre una imagen, por si ven que al momento de ejecutar el código salen las letras en blanco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listo. Después de batallar un poco para conseguir el resultado esperado, ya quedó finalmente la fijación del submenú a la izquierda.

Con tu script y adaptándolo un poco a lo que ya tenía diseñado, finalmente ya pude hacer que el submenú se muestre como quería.

Éste fue el resultado:

```css
.navlist {
    display: block;
}

.navlistmain {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    right: 0px;
    top: -5px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 20px;
}

.navlistmain a {
    display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
}

.navlistmain a:hover {
    background-color: #303030;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.navlistmain-sublist__subitem {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: -40px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.navlistmain-listmain__item,
.navlistmain-sublist {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navlistmain-sublist {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.navlistmain-listmain__item {
    flex: auto;
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 5px;
}

.navlistmain-listmain__item:hover
.navlistmain-sublist {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 15%;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<nav class="navlist">
            <ul class="navlistmain">
                <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 1</a>
                    <ul class="navlistmain-sublist">
                        <li class="navlistmain-sublist__subitem"><a href="#">Submenú 1</a></li>
                        <li class="navlistmain-sublist__subitem"><a href="#">Submenú 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 2</a>
                    <ul class="navlistmain-sublist">
                        <li class="navlistmain-sublist__subitem"><a href="#">Submenú 1</a></li>
                        <li class="navlistmain-sublist__subitem"><a href="#">Submenú 2</a></li>
                        <li class="navlistmain-sublist__subitem"><a href="#">Submenú 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 3</a></li>
                <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 4</a></li>
                <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 5</a></li>
                <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 6</a></li>
                <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 7</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
```

Esto lo adapté ahorita para mostrarlo aquí, ya que el menú original está adaptado para ser visto en la pantalla. Todo apunta a que no hacía falta poner tantos parámetros display flex, y bastaba poner none en display sobre el submenú para corregir el problema. O al menos, eso fue lo que pareció. El caso es que finalmente se corrigió la alteración del menú.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Ahora ya sólo falta adaptar agregar parámetros responsive al menú para que se vea de otra forma cuando mi sitio sea visitado por dispotivos móviles.

Answer (score 0):

- Si ya estás usando a *flexbox* entonces esta demás que hagas que los elementos sean flotantes, pues el primero mencionado nos ayuda a mover los elementos sobre alguno de los 2 ejes *(main-axis o cross-axis)*
- Cuando la maquetación *sea un tanto compleja* como esta es mejor que apliques clases que identifiquen elementos no solo de forma genérica sino además agrupada por características o función en común
- Para el caso anterior te voy a recomendar que leas sobre [BEM CSS](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/) **(sobre la cual sigo claramente aprendiendo)**
- Una vez claros esos puntos entonces podemos proceder del siguiente modo:

  - Al contenedor general **`ul`** le damos un **`display`** de tipo **`flex`**
  - El ancho lo podemos manejar de distintos modos, si por ejemplo queremos que abarque el 100% del *viewport* entonces lo hacemos con **`100vw`**
  - En conjunto con lo anterior para lograr que la distribución de cada elemento del menú sea uniforme, entonces hacemos uso de **`flex: auto;`** la cual resume a: [flex-shrink, flex-grow, flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex)
- Ahora para los `li` que dependen del submenú los ocultamos por medio de su clase `.navlistmain-sublist` con la propiedad de **`display: none;`** y dando un ancho del 100%
- Ahora para lograr el efecto de mostrar los elementos del submenú cuando se haga **`hover`** sobre algún elemento del primer nivel procedemos:

  - Invocamos a la clase que identifica a los elementos del menú del primer nivel indicando el uso de la pseudoclase **`hover`**
  - Invocamos inmediatamente después la clase que identifica a la etiqueta `ul` que contiene a los elementos del submenú
  - Para que aparezca nuevamente le damos un `display: block;`
  - Le damos un ancho máximo del 15%, (esto al gusto)
  - Le indicamos que tenga un posicionamiento de tipo [**`absolute`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position)

**NOTA**

> El resto de estilos que coloqué y no mencioné son solo para dar *un aspecto adornado* y *tratar de mejorar un poco la presentación* pero no son estrictamente relevantes para el caso en cuestión.

**CÓDIGO**

```html
    <style>
      * {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .navlistmain {
        display: flex;
        width: 100vw;
      }
      .navlistmain-listmain__item,
      .navlistmain-sublist {
        list-style-type: none;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
      }
      .navlistmain-sublist {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .navlistmain-listmain__item {
        flex: auto;
        text-align: center; 
        background-color: red;
        border-right: 1px solid;
      } 
      .navlistmain-listmain__item:hover
      .navlistmain-sublist {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: black;
        max-width: 15%;
        text-align: center; 
      }
    </style>
    
    <nav >
      <ul class="navlistmain">
        <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 1</a>
          <ul class="navlistmain-sublist">
            <li class="navlistmain-sublist__subitem"><a href="#">Opcion 1</a></li>
            <li class="navlistmain-sublist__subitem"><a href="#">Opción 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 2</a>
          <ul class="navlistmain-sublist">
            <li class="navlistmain-sublist__subitem"><a href="#">Opción 3</a></li>
            <li class="navlistmain-sublist__subitem"><a href="#">Opcion 4</a></li>
            <li class="navlistmain-sublist__subitem"><a href="#">Opción 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 3</a></li>
        <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 4</a></li>
        <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 5</a></li>
        <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 6</a></li>
        <li class="navlistmain-listmain__item"><a href="#">Menú 7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el dato. Iré probando con ensayo y error para ver cómo me resulta y te cuento. La verdad es que soy algo primerizo en CSS3, me sé lo más elemental por así decirlo, pero he notado que, conforme más profundizo en el lenguaje me topo con más parámetros, algunos un tanto difíciles de comprender su función, pero bueno. Saludos.

Comment: Claro @MauroMartin me avisas, ya solo es que lo adaptes